# jQuery : How to write this onblur event for dynamically inserting HTML element?

Tags: jquery

How to write this onblur event for dynamically inserting HTML element?
I am getting **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

```
var engraving_li = "<input type='text'
 id='engraving_txt_" + res[res.length-1] + "' 
 onblur='lengthCountOnBlur(this, "divcount_"+res[res.length-1]+")'  
 name='engraving_text[]' class='element text form-control' maxlength='20'
 placeholder='Engraving here (20 words)'  />";
$(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_"+res[res.length-1]);
```

This is the original element first I am removing and then inserting again as in above code

```
<input type="text" id="engraving_txt_<?php echo $add_number ?>" name="engraving_text[]"  class="element text form-control" maxlength="20" placeholder="Engraving here (20 words)"
value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['engraving_text']) && isset($_SESSION['engravingOption']) && $_SESSION['engravingOption'][$add_number-1]=='Yes') ? $_SESSION['engraving_text'][$add_number-1] : ''; ?>"
  onblur="lengthCountOnBlur(this, 'divcount_<?php echo $add_number; ?>');" onkeyup="limitTextCount(this, 'divcount_<?php echo $add_number; ?>', 20);" onkeydown="limitTextCount(this, 'divcount_<?php echo $add_number; ?>', 20);"/>
```

Comment: Can you share more details about the error you are getting.

Comment: @DanPhilip  this error is showing in browser console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: In which line is the exception occuring. You should be able to find it from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var engraving_li = "<input type='text' id = 'engraving_txt_" + res[res.length - 1] + "' onblur = \"lengthCountOnBlur(this,'divcount_" + res[res.length - 1] + "')\" name = 'engraving_text[]' class='element text form-control' maxlength= '20' placeholder = 'Engraving here (20 words)' />";
$(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_" + res[res.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a '+' sign in the string

```
onblur='lengthCountOnBlur(this, "divcount_"+res[res.length-1]+")'
```

It should be

```
onblur='lengthCountOnBlur(this, divcount_ + " res[res.length-1]+")'
```

Comment: this did not work, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string